# how can I debug my .save method on rails due it is not saving the information it should?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to save some information, actually editing one existing, and I created a form like this

```
%form{ :action => "/users/custom", :method => "post", :controller => "/users", data: {remote: true}}

 %input{:type => "text", :name => "name", :class => "text ", :value => " #{@current_user.first_name} #{@current_user.last_name}" }

 %input{:type => "text", :name => "age", :class => "text ", :value => " #{@current_user.age}" }
```

and I have others (weight, and address)... the problem that only one for "mail" with the exact same way of these fields is being persisted on the DB, but the other fields, for example age they get persisted with **0**

On my controller I have something like this

```
@user = User.find(session[:current_user])

@user.email = params[:mail]
@user.weight = params[:weight].to_i
... and so on...
  if @user.save
    flash[:notice] = 'The User is successfully saved!'
  end
```

any way to fix this? or to know what is wrong?

thanks

EDIT

```
Started POST "/users/custom" for 192.168.1.21 at 2013-05-08 15:50:04 -0600
Processing by UsersController#custom as JS
  Parameters: {"name"=>"name", "mail"=>"NEW MAIL", "sex"=>"1", "weight"=>"180" ... }
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `email` = 'NEW MAIL', `sex` = 0, `ssn` = 0, `updated_at` = '2013-05-08 21:50:04' WHERE `users`.`id` = 1
   (1.2ms)  COMMIT
```

editing the name doesnt work, the only thing that works its the email.

When I want to edit them with the scaffolds' default forms, I cant see the field weight and so on, just few, incluiding name (which from here I cant edit either)

My model has some restrictions.

```
validates :first_name, :format => { :with => /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/, :message => "Only letters allowed" }, :allow_blank => true
```

The problem is even if I remove it... keeps inserting 0... any idea?

Comment: Any reason you're not just using what Rails gives you for forms and parameters? Or `update_attributes`? First, check the params that are coming in, it's in the log.

Comment: [Debugging Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html) if you want to use what's already built in, if you want to take the extra step and make your life debugging Rails even easier check out [Better Errors and Rails Panel](http://railscasts.com/episodes/402-better-errors-railspanel).

Comment: could you please see my new edition? I added more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a debug breakpoint by doing: `binding.pry` anywhere in your controller action. Be sure to add the [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) gem to your `Gemfile` like so `gem 'pry'`.

Then execute your code and the breakpoint should hit in your server window for you to debug the problem.